# Quick way to check all values in a boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, boolean

I just started with java and while doing a web exercise, I created a Boolean array with 'n' length. After that, I decided to make a while loop that stop when all entries of the Boolean array are true. Is there a way to do this in a quick way? The only way I thought was putting "while(!(array[0] && array[1]... && array[n]), but it's a lot of work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Iterate  the list and check each element as true or false.

Comment: Have you heard of for loop?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go trough the whole list and check for true or false

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[] {false,true,true,false,true};
    int index = 0;
    while(!checkBooleanArray(array)) { //check
        array[index] = true;           //do something about it
        index++;                       //increasing the index and then check again
    }                                  //you obviously have to change the the part of "do something" and "increasing index" to match your wishes
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static boolean checkBooleanArray(boolean[] array) {
    for (boolean b : array)
        if (!b)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Another faster approach would be to try to sort the array when you change one of its booleans and then just check for the first or last boolean in the array

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so I need to put this whole statement inside the while loop?

Comment: No, the for loop already goes through the whole array

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it how I can apply in my situation. I understood that this enhanced-for goes thought my whole array, but my objective was: check if all of the entries are true. If not, do something and check again (do this thing untill all entries are true), if yes, break. To do so, I need to put this statement inside the while loop?

Comment: Oh sorry. Then of course yes, you need an while-loop. Gave you a example approach in main() (And fixed an error)